# Do I need to use definite article and commas in a defining relative clause?

Tags: grammar, definite-article, punctuation, relative-clauses, clauses

Do I need to use 'the' instead of 'a' here? Are the punctuation marks correct?

> She gave him a reason. A reason, that was sufficient to burst a passion inside him so that he could reveal all his feelings.

I was searching for some essay conclusions examples on the Internet and found the following:

> My attitudes have greatly shaped after this study. I have realized the ways meat impact our life and health. Meatless meals might improve the health conditions of patients suffering from various disorders, and the observed study proves it.

The source: https://pro-essay-writer.com/blog/essay-conclusion-examples

I wanted to use the first phrase in my own essay. I wonder if it is correct or not. Personally, I find it a bit weird. But maybe it is not so?

Comment: She gave him a reason, a reason sufficient to burst a passion inside him so that he could reveal all his feelings.

Comment: There is a grammatical error in your second quote.  It should be "the ways meat impacts". Also the word "conditions" is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading the intent of the sentence correctly, I would not put that comma between *reason* and *that*.  I *would* put one between *him* and *so* and drop the *that* between *so* and *he*, but you don't necessarily *have* to.

Paying no regards to stylistic choice, you could use:

- She gave him a reason. A reason that was sufficient to burst a passion inside him, so he could reveal all his feelings.
- She gave him a reason. The reason was sufficient to burst a passion inside him, so he could reveal all his feelings.
- She gave him a reason. That reason was sufficient to burst a passion inside him, so he could reveal all his feelings.
- She gave him a reason that was sufficient to burst a passion inside him, so he could reveal all his feelings.

With regards to your second phrase, I agree that it feels weird.  Some alternatives that feel more natural to me—depending on what you actually want to say—are:

- My attitudes have been greatly [shaped|formed|defined] by this study
- My attitudes have been greatly [changed|redefined] by this study
- My attitudes have greatly changed [as a result of|since reading] this study
- This study has greatly [shaped|formed|informed|defined] my attitudes.